# Matrix decomposition that is invariant to rotation in domain space

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, matrix-decomposition

Is there any matrix decomposition that is invariant to rotation in domain space?
SVD is invariant to rotation in range space (I believe), but not in domain space.

In other words, I am looking for a matrix decomposition for which applying some operation on the components is equivalent to rotating the elements of the matrix.

PS: My matrix is actually an image kind of array. Thus, when I rotate the matrix elements, I interpolate the values to get the new matrix.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by that *“SVD is invariant to rotation in range space”*? E.g., for $Q\in SO(3)\setminus\{I\}$ and $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$, the SVDs of $A$ and $QA$ are in general different. In particular, they are always different when $A$ is invertible.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/642849/516816) says that rotation in range space is defined as $QAQ^T$. If SVD of $A=U \Sigma V^T$, then $Q A Q^T = Q U Q^T Q \Sigma Q^T Q V^T Q^T$ i.e. we can apply the rotation operation to each of the components of $A$.